Star forming regions
Some star forming regions, like Bok globules (which contain stars that still haven't dispersed their molecular hydrogen and cosmic dust shell)  appear dark compared to the rest of the H II in which they form. Does this happen because the star hasn't ionized and transformed the molecular hydrogen in ionized atomic one?

Although it's pronounced the same, I think you mean "H$_2$" (molecular hydrogen) rather than "H II" (ionized hydrogen). Also, the answer is yes.
